# Connect to Vertica from SparklyR

Tags: apache-spark, vertica, azure-hdinsight, sparklyr

I am trying to read data from Vertica using SparklyR. Spark Context is created using Livy. Vertica needs two jar files for its driver and connector. However, jars are not uploaded to the Spark Context. So, Vertica class error pops up.

```
ver_jars <- c("wasbs://[path]/vertica-jdbc-9.3.0-0.jar",
                "wasbs://[path]/vetica-9.0.1-spark2.1_scala2.11.jar"
              )
spark_conf <- spark_config()
spark_conf$spark.executor.instances <- 3
spark_conf$spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled <- "false"
spark_conf$livy.jars <- ver_jars
#spark_conf$spark.jars <- ver_jars # no sucess with this also 
livy_conf <- livy_config(config = spark_conf, user = "user", password = "pass" ) 
sc <- spark_connect(master = "https://mycluster.azurehdinsight.net/livy/",
                    method = "livy",
                    config = livy_conf, 
                    version= "2.4.0"  
          )
ds <- spark_read_jdbc(sc, "myquery", repartition = 200, options = list(
  url = "jdbc:vertica://url:5433/",
  driver = 'com.vertica.spark.datasource.DefaultSource',
  user = "user",
  password = "pass",
  dbtable = paste0("(",sql, ")","as this_ds"))
)
```

Error is

```
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vertica.spark.datasource.DefaultSource
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.findClass(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:62)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverRegistry$.register(DriverRegistry.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$5.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$5.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:99)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

Comment: `spark2.1_scala2.11`? Doesn't look right... Are you sure it supports Spark 2.4?

Comment: It is forward compatible. Vertica has not provided a newer version for those jars. Those are the late. I can use them fine when doing scala spark.